# Select XPath of free child element without tag

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Having trouble selecting XPath of child element that doesn't have html tag and I need to select all the elements without html tag.

The child elements without any html tags looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6xDU.png).

Comment: could you please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to select the "64" value (in the image) you would use:

`response.xpath('//div[@class="spaceit"/text()')` for the selector object, if you want the value returned add a `.get()` or `.getall()` at the end of the line. [More info here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#constructing-selectors)

Of course, **without seeing the whole HTML I can't be sure of the results**, as there could be several `div` tags with the class `spaceit`.

I also would like to reinforce @Roman's comment, and ask in the future you to provide [Minimal Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @renatodvc's answer, 3 options to extract the number of episodes of FMAB from MAL :

```
response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[.="Episodes:"]/following::text()[1])')
response.xpath('normalize-space(//span[.="Episodes:"]/../text()[normalize-space()])')
response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="spaceit"][./span[.="Episodes:"]]/text()[normalize-space()])')
```

Output in these 3 cases : `64`